# How can I make this React code shorter? I feel like I'm repeating myself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

---

***Hi I know there is a way to make this code shorter. I'm repeating myself and it's practically the same. It's supposed to be the profile page where I show my picture, and social media:***

---

```js
const Profile = () => {
    return (
        <div className="profile">
            <div className="img-profile">
                <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/65257680?v=4" alt="" class="img-fluid"></img>
            </div>
            <div className="flexbox-perfil">
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/paulasierra7/" className="me-3">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-linkedin" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M0 1.146C0 .513.526 0 1.175 0h13.65C15.474 0 16 .513 16 1.146v13.708c0 .633-.526 1.146-1.175 1.146H1.175C.526 16 0 15.487 0 14.854V1.146zm4.943 12.248V6.169H2.542v7.225h2.401zm-1.2-8.212c.837 0 1.358-.554 1.358-1.248-.015-.709-.52-1.248-1.342-1.248-.822 0-1.359.54-1.359 1.248 0 .694.521 1.248 1.327 1.248h.016zm4.908 8.212V9.359c0-.216.016-.432.08-.586.173-.431.568-.878 1.232-.878.869 0 1.216.662 1.216 1.634v3.865h2.401V9.25c0-2.22-1.184-3.252-2.764-3.252-1.274 0-1.845.7-2.165 1.193v.025h-.016a5.54 5.54 0 0 1 .016-.025V6.169h-2.4c.03.678 0 7.225 0 7.225h2.4z"/>
                </svg>
                </a>
                <a href="https://github.com/paulasierra7/proyecto_react"  className="me-3">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-github" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.012 8.012 0 0 0 16 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z"/>
                </svg>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/paulasierra7/">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-instagram" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8 0C5.829 0 5.556.01 4.703.048 3.85.088 3.269.222 2.76.42a3.917 3.917 0 0 0-1.417.923A3.927 3.927 0 0 0 .42 2.76C.222 3.268.087 3.85.048 4.7.01 5.555 0 5.827 0 8.001c0 2.172.01 2.444.048 3.297.04.852.174 1.433.372 1.942.205.526.478.972.923 1.417.444.445.89.719 1.416.923.51.198 1.09.333 1.942.372C5.555 15.99 5.827 16 8 16s2.444-.01 3.298-.048c.851-.04 1.434-.174 1.943-.372a3.916 3.916 0 0 0 1.416-.923c.445-.445.718-.891.923-1.417.197-.509.332-1.09.372-1.942C15.99 10.445 16 10.173 16 8s-.01-2.445-.048-3.299c-.04-.851-.175-1.433-.372-1.941a3.926 3.926 0 0 0-.923-1.417A3.911 3.911 0 0 0 13.24.42c-.51-.198-1.092-.333-1.943-.372C10.443.01 10.172 0 7.998 0h.003zm-.717 1.442h.718c2.136 0 2.389.007 3.232.046.78.035 1.204.166 1.486.275.373.145.64.319.92.599.28.28.453.546.598.92.11.281.24.705.275 1.485.039.843.047 1.096.047 3.231s-.008 2.389-.047 3.232c-.035.78-.166 1.203-.275 1.485a2.47 2.47 0 0 1-.599.919c-.28.28-.546.453-.92.598-.28.11-.704.24-1.485.276-.843.038-1.096.047-3.232.047s-2.39-.009-3.233-.047c-.78-.036-1.203-.166-1.485-.276a2.478 2.478 0 0 1-.92-.598 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-.6-.92c-.109-.281-.24-.705-.275-1.485-.038-.843-.046-1.096-.046-3.233 0-2.136.008-2.388.046-3.231.036-.78.166-1.204.276-1.486.145-.373.319-.64.599-.92.28-.28.546-.453.92-.598.282-.11.705-.24 1.485-.276.738-.034 1.024-.044 2.515-.045v.002zm4.988 1.328a.96.96 0 1 0 0 1.92.96.96 0 0 0 0-1.92zm-4.27 1.122a4.109 4.109 0 1 0 0 8.217 4.109 4.109 0 0 0 0-8.217zm0 1.441a2.667 2.667 0 1 1 0 5.334 2.667 2.667 0 0 1 0-5.334z"/>
                </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Thanks!!**

Comment: The paths don't overlap (right? feel free to correct me), nor do the hrefs, nor do the class names. I think your current code is fine. It's not *perfectly* DRY, but sometimes being DRY comes at the expense of comprehensibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a component that has an anchor element on top of an svg, since you have repeated this multiple times. Make a component like this:

```
const ClickableSvg = ({link, svg}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <a href={link.url}>{link.text}</a>
      {svg}
    </>)
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
const Profile = () => {
    const data = [...] //this contains objects with a link and svg.
    return (
        <div className="profile">
            <div className="img-profile">
                <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/65257680?v=4" alt="" class="img-fluid"></img>
            </div>
            <div className="flexbox-perfil">
                {data.map((d)=> <ClickableSvg link={d.link} svg={d.svg} />)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

Where `data` in the code above is an array of objects that contain a link and svg property.